# unable to display div even if condition is true, always displaying else part in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to show div on tab click only if condition is true, but always i am getting else div which is displayed in else part even when if condition is true

```
 $('#err').removeClass('uk-active'); 
 $('#MA_st').addClass('uk-active');
```

i have tried above code on success ajax call and also tried the following on tab click

```
 $("#tab_list").on('click','li',function (){
      $('#err').removeClass('uk-active'); 
      $('#MA_st').addClass('uk-active');
 });
```

here is my php code to show div in view file

```
<?php 
  $state_val = "";
  if(isset($_GET['state_val'])){
    $state_val = $_GET['state_val'];
    print_r($state_val);
  }
  if($data['state'] == 'MA' || $state_val == 'MA'){?>
    <div id="MA_st">
      <li>
          <div class="uk-form-row">
              <label class="uk-form-label"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Number")?></label>
              <?php echo CHtml::textField('txt_number',
                  isset($data['number'])?$data['number']:""
                  ,array(
                      'class'=>'uk-form-width-large'
                  ))?>
          </div>

          <div class="uk-form-row">
              <label class="uk-form-label"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Name")?></label>
              <?php echo CHtml::textField('txt_name',
                  isset($data['name'])?$data['name']:""
                  //"ABC"
                  ,array(
                      'class'=>'uk-form-width-large',
                      'autocomplete'=>"off"
                  ))?>
          </div>
      </li>
  </div>
<?php }else{?>
    <div id="err">
    <p>Inforamtion is not avaialble</p>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe a typo, you don't close if/else statement. Do you get some errors?

Comment: what you get in the $data and check else closing.

Comment: @Sfili_81 3 else is closed in my code and m not getting any error it showing div in my response but not in browser

Comment: If your PHP code outputs either the element `#MA_st` or the element `#err`, then your JS code will hardly be able to find both at the same time. (Unless your AJAX call outputs the results of multiple calls to this with different parameters, but you didn’t show us anything about that.)

Comment: Maybe because you are binding click event on future elements,try  `$(document).on("click", '#tab_list li', function() {..`

Comment: @augustine jenin in $data getting state value from database

Comment: $(document).on('change','#state', function(){
    var state = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"controlername",
        data: {'state_val':state},
        success:function(data){
            alert('yes');
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert('err');
        }
    });
}); 
here is my ajax call @04FS

Comment: check your browser web console so you can check if you get some error from ajax call

Comment: So that AJAX call does nothing else but show an alert? Then the DOM is still the same as before, which means you have _either_ the element `#MA_st` in it, _or_ `#err`, but not both … so what elements do you want to “switch” between now, if there _is_ only one?

Comment: Can you print the $data?

Answer (score 0):

In either case of "If" or "Else" the  second div is not being rendered, JS needs both divs to be rendered properly, try something like

```
<?php
  $state_val = "";
  if(isset($_GET['state_val'])){
    $state_val = $_GET['state_val'];
    print_r($state_val);
  }
  if($data['state'] == 'MA' || $state_val == 'MA'){?>
<div id="MA_st" class="uk-active">
    <li>
        <div class="uk-form-row">
            <label class="uk-form-label"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Number")?></label>
            <?php echo CHtml::textField('txt_number',
            isset($data['number'])?$data['number']:""
            ,array(
            'class'=>'uk-form-width-large'
            ))?>
        </div>

        <div class="uk-form-row">
            <label class="uk-form-label"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Name")?></label>
            <?php echo CHtml::textField('txt_name',
            isset($data['name'])?$data['name']:""
            //"ABC"
            ,array(
            'class'=>'uk-form-width-large',
            'autocomplete'=>"off"
            ))?>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
<div id="err">
    <p>Inforamtion is not avaialble</p>
    <?php }else{?>
    <div id="MA_st">
        <li>
            <div class="uk-form-row">
                <label class="uk-form-label"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Number")?></label>
                <?php echo CHtml::textField('txt_number',
                isset($data['number'])?$data['number']:""
                ,array(
                'class'=>'uk-form-width-large'
                ))?>
            </div>

            <div class="uk-form-row">
                <label class="uk-form-label"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Name")?></label>
                <?php echo CHtml::textField('txt_name',
                isset($data['name'])?$data['name']:""
                //"ABC"
                ,array(
                'class'=>'uk-form-width-large',
                'autocomplete'=>"off"
                ))?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div id="err" class="uk-active">
        <p>Inforamtion is not avaialble</p>
    </div>
    }?>
```